# Android: How to catch or prevent FileProvider exception from NoNonsense FilePicker

Tags: java, android

**TL DR: Users are able to select a folder which isn't accounted for by the FileProvider, resulting in an exception which I can't catch or handle, killing my app.**

I'm developing an Android app, and I want the user to be able to select a folder on their device for my app to use. Because Android doesn't have a native folder picker, I'm using [spacecowboy's NoNonsense-FilePicker](https://github.com/spacecowboy/NoNonsense-FilePicker). It works well and looks good, but I'm running into one problem.

One of the steps in getting the FilePicker to work is setting up a FileProvider in your manifest. This is my FileProvider in my manifest:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/nnf_provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

and this is the nnf_provider_paths xml file that it references:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="root" path="/" />
</paths>
```

I've pointed it at the root of the external path. Users are able to select any folder at this path or below it, and the result is successfully handled and everything works great.

This is what it looks like.

[image: [2]]

However, if the user taps the ".." button at the top to move up a couple levels to just the "/storage" folder, they are in a Folder which hasn't been accounted for in the FileProvider. If they click Ok to select one of these folders, this fatal Exception occurs which crashes my app:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: my.app, PID: 29871
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage
at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:711)
at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:400)
at com.nononsenseapps.filepicker.FilePickerFragment.toUri(FilePickerFragment.java:201)
at com.nononsenseapps.filepicker.FilePickerFragment.toUri(FilePickerFragment.java:28)
at com.nononsenseapps.filepicker.AbstractFilePickerFragment.onClickOk(AbstractFilePickerFragment.java:314)
at com.nononsenseapps.filepicker.AbstractFilePickerFragment$2.onClick(AbstractFilePickerFragment.java:196)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

This error occurs *after* I start the FilePicker intent from my app, but *before* the onActivityResult, so I don't know how to catch it or handle it. Because of this, it is guaranteed to crash my app, and I have no way to prevent it because the user will always be able to move up a few levels and find a folder that I haven't accounted for in the FileProvider.

My question is:

1. Is there a way to catch the exception generated by the FilePicker in my app?
2. Is there a way to prevent users from selecting a folder outside of what the FileProvider is expecting?
3. What am I missing here? Why can't I find anyone else who has encountered this problem with FilePicker? How does everyone else handle the possibility of the user selecting a file that will throw this error?

This is the full code of the activity creating the dialog and receiving the result. Again, it works fine for files inside the folder set up in the FileProvider, but otherwise an Exception will occur without ever hitting onActivityResult.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.nononsenseapps.filepicker.FilePickerActivity;
import com.nononsenseapps.filepicker.Utils;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class ActivitySettings extends AppCompatActivity
{
    public static final int FILE_CODE = 1;
    public static final int FILE_CODE_RESULT_OK = -1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        try
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

            Button buttonSelectDirectoryImages = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectDirectoryImages);
            buttonSelectDirectoryImages.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        i.putExtra(FilePickerActivity.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, false);
                        i.putExtra(FilePickerActivity.EXTRA_ALLOW_CREATE_DIR, false);
                        i.putExtra(FilePickerActivity.EXTRA_MODE, FilePickerActivity.MODE_DIR);
                        i.putExtra(FilePickerActivity.EXTRA_START_PATH, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
                        startActivityForResult(i, FILE_CODE);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        try
        {
            if (requestCode == FILE_CODE && resultCode == FILE_CODE_RESULT_OK)
            {
                List<Uri> files = Utils.getSelectedFilesFromResult(data);
                for (Uri uri : files)
                {
                    File file = Utils.getFileForUri(uri);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), file.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help or hints.

Comment: Android does have a native folder picker on API 21+ in [ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)

Comment: Well what do you know. Yeah it looks like that will work better. Thanks for pointing that out.